# Finding common items between nested list and another list by casting them to set

Tags: python, list, lambda, set, higher-order-functions

I have the following two lists and I am trying to find the common words between them. I am trying to extract the words from `l2` (ignoring the number) and store them in `l3`, but I keep getting the error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not tuples

I am interested in a fix or if there is a better approach to the solution.

```
l1=['the', 'and', 'to', 'of', 'a', 'in', 'is', 'that']
l2=[('the', 637), ('of', 252), ('a', 208), ('to', 207), ('in', 147), 
    ('and', 134), ('that', 134), ('was', 133)]


l3= list(map(lambda x: set(l2[x][x]), l2[0:6]))

print(set(l1 & l3))
```

Comment: meant l2 or the paired tuples in side the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
s1 = set(l1)

i = s1.intersection( e[0] for e in l2 )

print(i) # set(['a', 'and', 'that', 'of', 'to', 'in', 'the'])
```

Set intersection (the method) can take any iterable to find the intersection with the set you call it on.

---

Your error stems from incorrectly using the lambda:

```
map(lambda x: set(l2[x][x]), l2[0:6]))
```

each `x` is one element of l2 (you only take the first six elements of `l2`. `map` takes each element of the input iterable and applies the function you provide. For the first element of `l2` this would be:

```
set(l2[('the', 637)][('the', 637)])
```

wich is clearly wrong.

Comment: Why did i get the error though: indices must be integers or slices, not tuples

Comment: Is it possible to for example index it? so i can only extract the words

Comment: @misu no - map would generate a list of lots of 1-element sets of each if you fix it - not the intersection between the l2 and l1 elements - `l1 & [ set(), set(), set(), set()]` wont work

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension, and check which tuple's first element is contained in `l1`. You can reduce the complexity of the operation by constructing a `set` from `l1`:

```
s1 = set(l1)

l3 = [s for s,*_ in l2 if s in s1]
# ['the', 'of', 'a', 'to', 'in', 'and', 'that']
```

Or we could use `zip` too and index on the first element:

```
set(l1).intersection(list(zip(*l2))[0])
```

---

Note that your approach is not working since you're trying to index using tuples . `lambda x` is receiving a tuple each time, since you're iterating over `l2` directly. If you have length `2` sublists, you could also consider working with dictionaries, which you *can*  access using a given key. Given the structure of your data, it looks like this could be a good alternative for you:

```
d = dict(l2)

[i for i in l1 if i in d]
# ['the', 'and', 'to', 'of', 'a', 'in', 'that']
```

Comment: Why did i get the error though: indices must be integers or slices, not tuples

Comment: @schwobaseggl ment eg:l2[0][0] to get the words only form the tuple

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access the tuples by the names of the firts elements? That would make sense with a dictionary @Misu Not tuples though

Answer (score 1):

To fix your own approach:

```
l3 = set(map(lambda x: x[0], l2))  # first element from each pair in l2

print(set(l1) & l3)  # must intersect set and set, not list and set
```

Comment: while this code works, the original OP approach will not properly work since will remove the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your list `l1` to a `set` and then you can use a list comprehension:

```
l1= ['the', 'and', 'to', 'of', 'a', 'in', 'is', 'that']
l1 = set(l1)

l2=[('the', 637), ('of', 252), ('a', 208), ('to', 207), ('in', 147), ('and', 134), ('that', 134), ('was', 133)]

l3 = [t[0] for t in l2 if t[0] in l1]
```